# Navigation menu href page's slug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can we update the menu to get href with page's slug instead of whole link?

By default with following code

**functions.php**

```
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

**header.php**

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) );
```

Outpu HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-4 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress_tester/first-page/">First
            page</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress_tester/second-page/">Second Page</a></li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress_tester/third-page/">Third Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

As I see "first-page", "second-page" and "third-page" are slugs of pages.
What can be done to update the menu links to

```
<a href="#first-page">First Page</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress_tester/first-page/">First Page</a>
```

Looks like one of [default arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) not give this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter: [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes). When you use this filter, you receive link attributes for each menu item and you can change them. 
The attributes for link looks like this:

```
array (size=4)
  'title' => string '' (length=0)
  'target' => string '' (length=0)
  'rel' => string '' (length=0)
  'href' => string '#menu-item-1' (length=37)
```

As you can see one of the given attributes is `href` attribute, so you can change it like this:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function($atts, $item, $args, $depth) {

    $atts['href'] = '#' . $item->post_name; //or what you want, here you have all WP_Post menu object

    return $atts;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: It's strange, but this filter doesn't do nothing, like other filters that I tried, may be something missed on my side? I have the minimum required clear theme, and have wp_nav_menu() function in header.php, but nothing changed after adding filter.

Comment: Did you have debug mode enabled to check for some php errors? How you apply this filter - with closure or with external function? I tried this filter and its work in my site.

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); I added the filter at the end functions.php file in "twentyfourteen" clear theme.

Comment: Unfortunately its very difficult to guess without being able to see your project files :( What about if you try to put `var_dump($atts)` after `$atts['href'] = '#' . $item->post_name;` line, to ensure that this code actually runs and `href` attribute is actually changed? A got result like this: see my edited answer for printed result.

Comment: Another suggestion I can give you is to use custom walker which extends `Walker_Nav_Menu` and rewrite `start_el` function as you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use custom link of Wordpress menu. [Read this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen#Custom_Links)